# Swift : How to convert String to string with time format?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have string values include time with formatted **"HH:mm"** (16:50)

i have to convert this value to **"hh:mm**" format (04:50) as a string in SWIFT

i have tried NSDateFormatter like

```
let timeFormat = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormat.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
var dateFromStr = timeFormat.dateFromString("16:50")
var strFromDate = timeFormat.stringFromDate(dateFromStr)
```

but its not working..
Please tell any solution.

Comment: Just a wild guess.... shouldn't it be `var date_from_str = time_format.dateFromString("16:50")` ?

Comment: why my question get downvote? and first answer erased from page while thats true.. what is going on here

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but did you look at the http://stackoverflow.com/tour ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need 2 `NSDateFormatter`s, one for `dateFromString`, one for `stringFromDate`

```
let inFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
inFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
inFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

let outFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
outFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
outFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

let inStr = "16:50"
let date = inFormatter.dateFromString(inStr)!
let outStr = outFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
println(outStr) // -> outputs 04:50
```

> Swift 5

```
let inFormatter = DateFormatter()
inFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
inFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ssa"

let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
outFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
outFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
 
let inStr = "16:50"       
let datess = inFormatter.date(from: inStr)!
let outStr = outFormatter.string(from: datess)
print(outstr)
```

Answer (score 7):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**

```
func dateTimeChangeFormat(str stringWithDate: String, inDateFormat: String, outDateFormat: String) -> String {
    let inFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    inFormatter.dateFormat = inDateFormat

    let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    outFormatter.dateFormat = outDateFormat

    let inStr = stringWithDate
    let date = inFormatter.date(from: inStr)!
    return outFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

usage:

```
let outStr = dateTimeChangeFormat(str: "16:50", 
                                  inDateFormat:  "HH:mm", 
                                  outDateFormat: "hh:mm")

println(outStr) // -> outputs 04:50
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved by using one `DateFormatter`.

Plus added some extra format in one place. Hope someone get help.

**Xcode 12 - Swift 5.3**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
var dateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from: "16:50")!

// Time with date in long format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
var timeInLongFromDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
print(timeInLongFromDate)
// 04:50:00 PM on January 01, 2000

// Time with customisable format
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
var timeFromDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
print(timeFromDate)
// 04:50:00 PM

// Customisable AP/PM symbols
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "Pm"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "a"
var amOrPm = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
print(amOrPm)
// Pm
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should write the time inside the string.

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("00:00")
    var str_from_date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate (date)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I think it's worth noting that [`isLenient`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1411441-islenient) allows you to use 1 formatter instead of 2.

```swift
func normalizeTimeString(_ original: String) -> String? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.isLenient = true
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

    guard let date = formatter.date(from: original) else { return nil }
    let corrected = formatter.string(from: date)
    return corrected
}

normalizeTimeString("16:50") // Returns "04:50"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 func hrs12FormateString(date:String)-> String {
        let inFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
        inFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
        outFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
        outFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"  
        let inStr = date 
        let date = inFormatter.date(from: inStr)!
        let outStr = outFormatter.string(from: date)
        return outStr
    }
```